# MvcSiteMapProvider attribute does not work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, breadcrumbs, mvcsitemapprovider

I try to use MvcSiteMapProvider for breadcrumbs.

I have the following sitemap file:

```
<mvcSiteMap xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns="http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/schemas/MvcSiteMap-File-4.0"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/schemas/MvcSiteMap-File-4.0 MvcSiteMapSchema.xsd">

  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Home" controller="Home" action="Index" key="Index">
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="About" controller="Home" action="About"/>
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Company List" controller="Company" action="Index" key="Company">
      <mvcSiteMapNode title="Create company" controller="Company" action="Create" />
    </mvcSiteMapNode>
  </mvcSiteMapNode>

</mvcSiteMap>
```

and display it:

```
                @Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMapPath()
```

it works fine for pages "Create Company", "Company List" etc

then I want to add it for action with parameters:

```
        [MvcSiteMapNode(Title = "Company Details", ParentKey = "Company", Key = "CompanyDetails")]
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
...
            CompanyDetailVM model = mapper.Map<CompanyDetailVM>(company);
            return View(model);
        }
```

but it does not work, no show breadcrumbs at all. Where is a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `id` route parameter to the sitemap node:

```
[MvcSiteMapNode(Title = "Company Details", ParentKey = "Company", Key = "CompanyDetails", PreservedRouteParameters = "id")]
    public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        ...
    }
```